# Como validar que no hayan combobox seleccionados

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola mi pregunta es que de que manera puedo validar que para el caso que no haya ningún combobox seleccionado arroje un error.

Normalmente es al revés con las validaciones, en donde se pregunta que al menos haya uno o varios combobox seleccionados, o cajas de texto o alguna variable, para luego seguir con el envío del formulario, preguntando si la cadena está o no vacía y **comúnmente** es por algún control en específico, el cual se identifica por el nombre o el id de un objeto en concreto.

El siguiente ejemplo que tengo muestra un poco a lo que me refiero:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> /*NOTA:Los mensajes del alert no son importantes*/
  function validaSelects(){ 
  if (document.formAlertas.RutaAl.value == "")
     {
        alert("No sea pillo. Seleccione una opción");
        return false;

    } else if(document.formAlertas.UsuariosA.value == "" ) 
        {
            alert("Segunda Advertencia, debe seleccionar una opcion.");
            return false;
        }
        else if (document.formAlertas.RegionA.value=="")
            {
                alert("Tercera Advertencia, deberá seleccionar una opción.");
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.formAlertas.ClientesA.value=="") 
            {
                alert("Se lo advertimos ya no podrá continuar");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                document.formAlertas.submit(); 
            }
      }

   </script>
```

Este ejemplo lo hice yo tratando de lograr el propósito final, lo que hace es preguntar si alguno de esos combobox se seleccionó y luego arroja un error por cada combobox que no se haya seleccionado.

Otra  manera que probé fue que junté los 2 primeros combobox y los comparé con un OR, luego con un si-no pregunte por los 2 siguientes combobox y los comparé también con || y por cada comparación arrojaba un mensaje de error, cosa que tampoco era lo que buscaba como propósito final.

Pero indistintamente de aquello que comenté en un principio lo que quiero hacer es algo completamente distinto, el propósito es hacer una validación en donde el error lo arroje siempre y cuando no haya **ningún** combobox seleccionado, y luego el caso que exista **Al Menos 1 combo** seleccionado (*Cualquiera que sea*) prosiga con el envío del formulario. Ojala con javascript que es lo que estuve probando y es más simple.

Comment: Podrías preguntar por cada combobox (si tiene selección hecha), y en vez de mostrar un mensaje o cortar el flujo de la secuencia de validaciones, aumentas un contador (una variable int); la idea es que pases por todos los comboboxes, independiente de si fallan o no, y luego al final preguntas por el valor de la variable: en este caso, la comparas con el total de comboboxes validados. Ejemplo, son 4 comboboxes, y 3 de ellos dicen no tener valor, al restar, signfica que 1 sí lo tiene, y eso ya te sirve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si deseas verificar si todos los select tienen valor puedes recorrer el formulario donde se encuentran e ir concatenando en una variable el valor de los mismos. Si al concluir el largo de la cadena es 0 quiere decir que ninguno tenia valor, sino al menos 1 estuvo con valor.

Asumiendo que este sea mas o menos tu estructura html:

```js
var form = document.querySelector("#form1"); 
var validateForm = function(){
    var combos = document.querySelectorAll("select");
    var val = '';
    for(var i=0;i<combos.length;i++){
     val += combos[i].value;
    }
    var result = (val.length > 0);
    if(!result){
     alert("Debe seleccionar uno de los combobox");
    }
    return result;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" onsubmit="Javascript: return validateForm();">
 <select id="combo1">
  <option value="">Seleccione 1</option>
  <option>Dariel</option>
 </select>
 <select id="combo2">
  <option value="">Seleccione 1</option>
  <option>Dariel</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te muestro una solución muy practica, la cual es recorrer los elementos del formulario y validar uno a uno verificando si el cliente no ha seleccionado una opción valida de los elementos select, le muestras un mensaje genérico (**Habias mencionado que el mensaje no era importante**):

```
function validaSelects() {
   var combos = document.querySelectorAll("select");
    for (let index = 0; index < combos.length; index++) {
        if (!combos[index].value) {
            alert("Debe completar los campos antes de continuar");
            return;
        }
    }
    document.formAlertas.submit();
}
```

Comment: Hola, ten cuidado, esta respuesta no solo verifica los combobox sino todos los elementos del formulario, pueden haber otro tipo de elementos en el formulario que no sean combobox y que no deban validarse, saludos.

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta en base a tu inquietud. gracias!